# CSS 2.1 first-letter not validating

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When I validate my CSS using the W3 validator, I get the following error message:

> The pseudo-element ::first-letter can't appear here in the context css21 [first-letter]

This is what the CSS looks like:

```
#numbersWrapper p span::first-letter, #numbersWrapper p::first-letter, #lettersWrapper p span::first-letter, #lettersWrapper p::first-letter{
  font-size:17px;
} 

span{
  display:inline-block
}
```

And a section of my HTML:

```
<div id="lettersWrapper">
<h3 id="MSL">Maritme Signals: Letters</h3>
<div class="textWrapper">
<p>A - <span>Alpha</span>
<br/><img src= (REMOVED)
    alt="I have a diver down; keep well clear at slow speed."
    title="I have a diver down; keep well clear at slow speed."/></p>
<p>B - <span>Bravo</span>
<br/><img src= (REMOVED)
    alt="I am taking in, or discharging, or carrying dangerous goods."
    title="I am taking in, or discharging, or carrying dangerous goods."/></p>
```

Does anyone know why it won't validate? I've looked online a little and I think (if I've understood correctly), you can't chain elements and then use first-letter. However this doesn't seem right since it definitely works when viewing the page in Chrome.

Comment: Why would you choose the 2.1 profile?

Answer (score 0):

CSS 2.1's pseudo-elements (including `first-letter`) should only have one `:`. Your code should look like the following:

```css
#numbersWrapper p span:first-letter, #numbersWrapper p:first-letter, #lettersWrapper p span:first-letter, #lettersWrapper p:first-letter{
  font-size:17px;
} 

span{
  display:inline-block
}
```

Comment: Oh wow something so simple, thanks! Can I ask why the W3Schools example uses two?

Comment: It originally was only one colon. When they moved to CSS3 selectors it became two colons. You can see it in the specs CSS 3 (https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-letter) vs CSS 2.1 (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter)

Comment: I should mention, I assumed you were using a CSS 2.1 validator since it said "css21" in the error message. Edit: Also, didn't notice your title mentions it.